# RemoteRef not defined despite manually defining it - Julia

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, julia

I am using Julia version 0.6.2 and come across an error on line 15 stating RemoteRef is not defined. However, when I try and define it e.g. `RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(x,y,z)` I still get the same error. `@spawn` is used to also link it to another function later on in the could and `fetch()` is also used in the code to link it back in. This used to work on version 0.4.7 but I am trying to update the code.

I tried manually adding the RemoteRef to the repository.Refs list, but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone lend any insight into this issue? Thank you.

```
 Pkg.add("DataFrames")
 Pkg.clone("git://github.com/wkearn/RasterIO.jl")
 Pkg.build("RasterIO")

using DataFrames
using RasterIO

output_file = "point_irradiance.asc"
dtm_file = "///dtm.tif"
dsm_file = "///dsm.tif"
buildings_file = "///build.asc"
extent_file = "///extent.dat"
lamps_file = "////pen_light.csv"
lamp_easting = 3
lamp_northing = 4
lamp_height = 2

@everywhere function lightdist(xdist,ydist,zdist)
    xyzdist = sqrt(xdist^2+ydist^2+zdist^2)
    return (1/(xyzdist^2))
end

function create_point_irradiance()    
    # Read in locations of street maps


    lamps = convert(Matrix, readtable(lamps_file))

    extent = convert(Matrix, DataFrames.readtable(extent_file))
    xindex = collect(extent[1,1]:1:(extent[1,2]-1))
    yindex = collect(extent[1,4]:-1:(extent[1,3]+1))
    xindexmax, = size(xindex)
    yindexmax, = size(yindex)

    nlamps, = size(lamps)
    nlamps = nlamps
    nprocs = 3
    chunk = div(nlamps, nprocs)
    references = Array(RemoteRef, nprocs)

    for core in 1:nprocs
        if (core == 1)
            from = 1
        else
            from = (chunk * (core - 1)) + 1
        end
        if (core == nprocs)
            to = nlamps
        else
            to = chunk * core
        end
        references[core] = @spawn calculate_shadow(lamps[from:to, :], dtm_file, dsm_file, buildings_file, xindex, yindex, xindexmax, yindexmax, lamp_easting, lamp_northing, lamp_height)
    end

    point_irradiance = fill(0.0, (yindexmax, xindexmax))

    for core in 1:nprocs
        point_irradiance += fetch(references[core])
    end

    writedlm(output_file, point_irradiance, " ")

    function add_headers(f::IOStream)
        return string("NCOLS ", xindexmax, "\n",
                      "NROWS ", yindexmax, "\n",
                      "XLLCORNER ", extent[1,1], "\n",
                      "YLLCORNER ", extent[1,3], "\n",
                      "CELLSIZE 2 \n",
                      "NODATA_VALUE -9999\n",
                      readall(f))
    end
    content = open(add_headers, output_file);
    f = open(output_file, "w")
    write(f, content)
    close(f)
end

@everywhere function calculate_shadow(lamps, dtm_file, dsm_file, buildings_file, xindex, yindex, xindexmax, yindexmax, lamp_easting, lamp_northing, lamp_height)

    ext = 100
    lamp_ext = 100
    absorbance = 0.1
    sensor_ht = 2.5

    dtmR = RasterIO.openraster(dtm_file, UInt32(0))
    dtm = transpose(RasterIO.fetch(dtmR, 1))
    RasterIO.closeraster(dtmR)

    dsmR = RasterIO.openraster(dsm_file, UInt32(0))
    dsm = transpose(RasterIO.fetch(dsmR, 1))
    RasterIO.closeraster(dsmR)

    buildingsR = RasterIO.openraster(buildings_file, convert(UInt32, 0))
    buildings = transpose(RasterIO.fetch(buildingsR, 1))
    RasterIO.closeraster(buildingsR)

    # Produce raster of structures (buildings, trees, hedges, etc)
    surf = dsm - dtm

    buildings = [if (buildings[ydim, xdim] == 0)
                 0
                 else
                 surf[ydim, xdim]
                 end
                 for ydim =1:yindexmax, xdim=1:xindexmax]

    hard_surf = dtm + buildings
    soft_surf = surf - buildings

    # release memory
    dsm = 0
    surf = 0
    buildings = 0

    point_irradiance = fill(0.0, size(hard_surf))

    for lamp in 1:size(lamps, 1)
        x = lamps[lamp,lamp_easting]
        y = lamps[lamp,lamp_northing]
        z = lamps[lamp,lamp_height]

        Xmax = xindex[xindexmax, 1]
        Xmin = xindex[1, 1]
        Ymin = yindex[yindexmax, 1]
        Ymax = yindex[1, 1]

        if ((x <= (Xmax+ext)) & (x>= (Xmin-ext)) & (y<=(Ymax+ext)) & (y>=(Ymin-ext)))
            row = find(yindex .== min(max(y,Ymin),Ymax))[1]
            col = find(xindex .== max(min(x,Xmax),Xmin))[1]
            col_min = max(col-ext,1)
            col_max = min(col+ext, xindexmax)
            col_lamp = col-col_min
            row_min = max(row-ext, 1)
            row_max = min(row+ext, yindexmax)
            row_lamp = row-row_min
            nrows = row_max-row_min
            ncols = col_max-col_min

            hard_block = hard_surf[row_min:(row_min + nrows - 1),col_min:(col_min + ncols - 1)]
            soft_block = soft_surf[row_min:(row_min + nrows - 1),col_min:(col_min + ncols - 1)]
            terrain_block = dtm[row_min:(row_min + nrows - 1),col_min:(col_min + ncols - 1)]

            point_irrad = fill(0.0, size(hard_block))

            if (ncols==200&nrows==200)
                for xx in 1:ncols
                    for yy in 1:nrows
                        xdist = col_lamp-xx
                        ydist = row_lamp-yy
                        xydist = sqrt(xdist^2+ydist^2)
                        zdist = (terrain_block[row_lamp,col_lamp]+z)-(terrain_block[yy,xx]+sensor_ht)
                        xyzdist = sqrt(xydist^2+zdist^2)
                        dist = floor(xydist+0.5)
                        if (xydist<=lamp_ext)
                            if (zdist>0)
                                shadow = 1
                                shading = 0
                                if(dist>0)
                                    for d in 1:dist
                                        if (hard_block[round(Int, yy+(ydist)*(d/dist)),round(Int, xx+(xdist)*(d/dist))] >= (terrain_block[yy,xx]+sensor_ht+(d/dist)*zdist))

                                            shadow = 0
                                        end
                                        if(soft_block[round(Int, yy+(ydist)*(d/dist)),round(Int, (xx+(xdist)*(d/dist)))] >= (terrain_block[yy,xx]+sensor_ht+(d/dist)*zdist))
                                            shading = shading + xyzdist/xydist
                                        end
                                        end

                                    end
                                    res = (1/(10^(absorbance*shading)))*shadow*lightdist(xdist,ydist,zdist)
                                    real_y = yy + row_min - 1
                                    real_x = xx + col_min - 1
                                    point_irradiance[real_y, real_x] = point_irradiance[real_y, real_x] + ((1/(10^(absorbance*shading)))*shadow*lightdist(xdist,ydist,zdist))
                                end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
            return point_irradiance
end

@time create_point_irradiance()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably the line `references = Array(RemoteRef, nprocs)` should be changed to `references = Array{Future}(nprocs)`. Note that you are overriding the Julia function `nprocs()` with a *Int* value (here => `nprocs = 3`)

Comment: ok thank you. I am away on fieldwork until tomorrow so I will try that then. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Gomiero. this then further creats an error: methoderror: no method matching +(::Array(Float64,2,::Remoteexception). any idea?

Comment: It's hard to say where this error occur wihtout see the entire code. Since this code was developed for Julia 0.4 and there are notable changes from this version to the current version (0.6), perhaps more errors like this will be raised when executing it. It looks like the error is at `calculate_shadow` function, but, again, I'm not sure of that

Comment: I have added the entire script. thanks

Comment: as far as I can tell the error might be coming from this line   `for core in 1:nprocs
        point_irradiance += fetch(references[core])
    end`

Comment: `fetch(references[core])` should return the result of `@spawn calculate_shadow` (executed in parallel), and add this result to the array `point_irradiance` (Array{Float64,2}), but, instead, the message shows that the `fetch` is returning a *Remoteexception*, so the real error is (probably) happening somewhere inside `calculate_shadow`.

Comment: ok thank you. Ill look there